# Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.37.3 ...-snip-...) were not met

Tags: command-line, gnome, makefile, automake

I'm attempting to compile the Gnome System Monitor and I'm running into an error when executing `./configure`. Not sure what packages are required here as I've attempted to apt-get libgtop-2.0 and librsvg-2.0.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.37.3
  libgtop-2.0 >= 2.28.2
  gtk+-3.0 >= 3.22.0
  gtkmm-3.0 >= 3.3.18
  libxml-2.0 >= 2.0
  librsvg-2.0 >= 2.35
  glibmm-2.4 >= 2.46
  giomm-2.4 >= 2.46
  gmodule-2.0
) were not met:

No package 'libgtop-2.0' found
Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.22.0' but version of GTK+ is 3.18.9
No package 'librsvg-2.0' found
```

Comment: When compiling things, you also need the `-dev` package sof each library.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/gnome/gnome-system-monitor.html)  see if the process was different from yours.

Comment: I had to find the 2 packages in synaptic to properly install them. I still have the line. "Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.22.0' but version of GTK+ is 3.18.9"

Comment: Well that seems pretty self-explanatory, no? You have version 3.18.9 of GTK+, but the program you are trying to compile requires at least 3.22.0. No version of Ubuntu currently has 3.22, but 17.04 will.

Comment: @The Confusled, try the [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html) I gave you you will get a `version` that is required. Compile instructions are they too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already solved it a long time ago, but, for the future readers, here are the names of dev packages which were really tough to find:

```
$ sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev libgtop2-dev librsvg2-dev
```

I find it so frustrating that there is a package `libgtop-2.0-10`, but for the dev version, it's neither `libgtop-2.0-dev` nor `libgtop-2.0-10-dev`. It's `libgtop2-dev`, go figure that.